# SQL merge 2 result in one

Tags: mysql, merge, union, concatenation

here the thing : 
I have two table. One contains customer with website and another table contain optionnal website of the customer.

I want to know if there is dupplicate website in the 2 table

For example :

tableA :

```
cust_id   cust_website
1            aaaa@aaa.a
2            bbbb@bbb.b
3            cccc@ccc.c
4            aaaa@aaa.a
5            dddd@ddd.d
...
```

tableB

```
cust_id    cust_optionnalWebsite
3          uuuu@uuu.u
4          dddd@ddd.d
...
```

I would like to have all dupplicate website in tableA, table B and tableAB. Well, all dupplicate..

I started to do like this :

```
SELECT cust_website FROM tableA WHERE cust_website IN (SELECT cust_optionnalWebsite FROM tableB UNION SELECT cust_website FROM tableA) GROUP BY cust_website  HAVING COUNT(cust_website) > 1
```

but UNION statement takes sooo much time, and obviously, it's missing something...

I also tried replace UNION by OR statement, but if there is the same website in tableA and tableB, it doesn't take two result but just one.

the output that I want is

website
aaaa@aaa.a
dddd@ddd.d

please help,

thank you

**EDIT :**

Finally this works :

```
SELECT website FROM ( SELECT cust_optionnalWebsite as website FROM tableB UNION ALL SELECT cust_website as website FROM tableA ) GROUP BY website HAVING(website)>1;
```

Comment: If a query takes too long, try to optimize it with index

Comment: Can you show us the output you want?

Comment: I added the output that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL merge 2 result in one:

```
1.) use UNION ALL
```

There's a lot of causes why you are getting slow when executing a query.

```
1.) Machine specs.
2.) Database Structure.
3.) Indexes.
4.) Database Software it self.
```

Comment: then what do you do

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but UNION ALL is really realy slow...I can not take that

Comment: Until you tell us otherwise, this seems like the way to go.

Comment: Do I need to create a temporary table ? I'm sure there is a better way than create a temporary table. (sorry for the misunderstanding)

Comment: Creating a temporary is not a better way, all of your query depends on your table structure. No sense

Comment: The UNION itself take 432ms, but included in the query, it take forever

Comment: Avoid using * if you dont need all table fields, just select the fields you wanted to use. Best practice

Comment: I finally accept UNION ALL but, also, I did put the UNION all in the FROM statement like this : 

SELECT website FROM (...UNION ALL.....) ..etc;